# Strange "Out of Memory" Error

Tags: android

My app is running properly on some Android devices but on some devices it's giving an out of memory error.

Here is the LogCat log:

http://logcat.miui-dev.com/147001

What this Activity does is load Bitmaps, and display those Bitmaps through `onDraw()`.

What would cause this error?

what am doing ?

Am just maping all images in a method image

_bitmapCache.put(R.drawable.gb2, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
                getResources(), R.drawable.gb2));

and when a constructor is called i call that method , while using image i just use

canvas.drawBitmap(_bitmapCache.get(R.drawable.level1c1), 0, 0, null);

to craw the image

Comment: did you searched for this? http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Strange+%E2%80%9COut+of+Memory%E2%80%9D+Error+android

Comment: yes , it didnt resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are requesting an 18 meg image.  You need to scale your images way down.  Each app is only allowed 16-24megs of heap space.  I'd have to see more of your code to make further suggestions, but an 18 meg image is really too large and the ImageView doesn't do the best job of automatically scaling the images, so you usually have to do the scaling before display in my experience.

Comment: You are loading all of your bitmaps into drawables and storing them into a hashmap in your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify in the Options of BitmapFactory a [inSampleSize](http://d.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize) that will allow to directly load a scaled down version of the Bitmap.

Comment: It does. But handling large pictures is not a simple issue. In my app EmailAlbum, I had to implement this http://code.google.com/p/emailalbum/source/browse/EmailAlbumAndroid/tags/REL-2_10_2/src/com/kg/emailalbum/mobile/util/BitmapLoader.java to load pictures in a downsized version and cache them.